# Is it common to use "where" after "a time" as a relative?

Tags: grammar, contemporary-english

I heard the following comment of Mr. Marco Rubio about Mr. Donald Trump on CBS’s “Face the Nation” in a clip in February 29th AP Radio News:

> “There is never gonna be **a time where** the Republican Party rallies
> around and says you have to get out or anyone has to get out for
> purposes of rallying around Donald Trump. Donald Trump is not
> Republican Conservative. Donald Trump is trying to pull off the
> biggest scam in American political history.”

I thought I misheard “There is never gonna be a time where –“ for “There is never gonna be a time when –“ at first, because I was in understanding that time should be trailed by “when” as a relative noun or adverb.
An English Japanese dictionary at hand (Readers English Japanese Dictionary published by Kenkyusha) provides “where” singly as a relative to refer the ‘place.’

However, my lookup of the following two sources endorsed that I heard it right:

> Here is what is never going to happen in this race. There's never
> going to be **a time where** the Republican Party rallies around and says
> you have to get out or anyone has to get out for purposes of rallying
> around Donald..
> [- Source](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/face-the-nation-transcripts-february-28-2016-trump-cruz-rubio-sanders/)
>
> “Here is what is never going to happen,” Rubio continued. “There's
> never going to be **a time where** the Republican Party rallies around and
> says you have to get out or anyone has to ...
>
> [- Source Link](https://www.yahoo.com/politics/marco-rubio-can-still-beat-donald-trump-no-)

Is it common, at least not uncommon to use “where” after “time” as a relative?

Comment: I think this is likely a dialect thing: I would always consider the "proper" form to be "a time when" but I know some areas colloquially use "where" as a substitute.

Comment: It seems to me that "a time when" is so obviously a better phrasing that "a time where" that the latter seems to be merely an artifact of misspeaking in extemporaneous remarks. A more difficult call involves "a situation where" versus "a situation in which": here, the latter wording seems more proper in a technical sense, given that a situation is not the same as a physical location; but "in which" is stiff and formal, and "a situation where," in contrast, runs trippingly and un-self-consciously off the tongue.

Comment: It's not exceedingly common, but is certainly used.  I might use it in a slightly different context -- perhaps something like "in a time where smarphones are sentient and money is obsolete."  I would guess that "where" becomes more attractive when one wants to emphasize the existence of a new era,with paradigm shifts.  That may have been Mr. Rubio's intent here, but it's a bit of a stretch,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Time where" is not as idiomatic as "time when", but not impossible. More broadly used noun with the relative adverb *where* is "period" as in:

[image]

[European Community Contract Law, Volume 1]

If you consider the "time" used in the Marco Rubio's sentence as "a block of time" which you can visualize in a timeline, there is no reason that you can't use *where* after *time* as in:

[image]

[The Practice of Cloud System Administration: Designing and ..., Volume 2]

Also, [time](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/time) is synonymous with *instance* or *occurrence* (Definition 3.4 in Wiktionary).

It is a safe bet to say that you can use "where" after "time" when it is synonymous with *instance* or *situation (circumstance)* as in:

> There is never gonna be an **instance** (*situation / circumstance*) where the Republican Party rallies
>   around and says you have to get out or anyone...

Answer (score 3):

The usage of "where" meaning "in which" referring to contexts different from a place has become commonly accepted now, as stated below by the Collins Dictionary:

***[Where](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/where)*** (Usage note):

> - It was formerly considered incorrect to use where as a substitute for in which after a noun which did not refer to a place or position, but this use has now become acceptable: we now have a situation where/in which no further action is needed.

The expression you noted " a time where" has become more commonly used in the recent decades:

***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20time%20where%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20time%20where%3B%2Cc0)***: *a time where*. 
***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20time%20where%2C%20a%20time%20in%20which%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20time%20where%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20time%20in%20which%3B%2Cc0)***: *a time where vs a time in which*.