# How to choose between "where" and "when" after the expression "There hasn't been a moment...."?

Tags: word-choice, that, when, where

There hasn't been a moment where/when science has ceased to amaze me. What do I choose?
I have also seen use of "that" in some cases:
There hasn't been a time that I haven't loved you.

Comment: Or you could leave it out altogether.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it common to use "where" after "a time" as a relative?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313189/is-it-common-to-use-where-after-a-time-as-a-relative). The metaphorical broadening of 'time' etc (here, 'moment') for 'instance', 'situation' is brought out by user 140086. 'When' is the more common choice when the precursor is overtly (ie formally) time-related (as here).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it common to use "where" after "a time" as a relative?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313189/is-it-common-to-use-where-after-a-time-as-a-relative)

Comment: @KillingTime Where _do_ CVs disappear to? And why?

Comment: [Meta SE: Why do close votes expire?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120896/why-do-close-votes-expire)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in informal contexts, *where* is used to introduce a defining relative clause referring back to a place, and "when" to a time.

So, "There hasn't been a moment when science has ceased to amaze me." is more idiomatic.

Read more about *Relative Pronouns* here: [English Grammar Today (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/relative-pronouns)